# Accuracy of GPS coordinates found in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I'm working on a project which requires constant location updates of my android phone. It works alright but, is highly inaccurate. Indoors i was getting accuracy of fetched location (via getAccuracy()) to be around 60(which as far as i know is in meters), where as i want accuracy to be in (at max) 2-3 meters.
Firstly, Is't possible to obtain accuracy of (2-3 meters) constantly?
If Yes, how?

Follow is the code piece i'm using to fetch user location.

```
    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{
    //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult = result;

    if(lm==null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
    try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
    try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        return false;

    if(gps_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
    if(network_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
    timer1=new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 10000);
    return true;
}
```

I was also getting another issue, with my device constantly placed at a static location, the distance between two successive GPS Location fetched is highly unreliable, it changes from 0.0 meters to 16meters, which means that my device is constantly moving.

If any of you have any idea about this preferably how to achieve accuracy please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using solely mintime and mindistance, you might get better results by passing in a Criteria object with

```
ACCURACY_FINE
POWER_HIGH
```

Your individual phone and physical environment will obviously impact the readings. You will likely overall get better results allowing the system to do some of the work for you by not specifying the exact location provider with the following call and criteria.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long, float, android.location.Criteria, android.location.LocationListener, android.os.Looper)

Answer (score 1):

Building on Pork's answer, you can reduce the variance a little bit in the case you present above (samples with variable accuracy) if you are flexible with your update frequency.  Let's say you define your desired frequency at 0.1 hz (update every 10 secs), then you can filter your location updates by only operating on the "best" location from the set of samples from the last 10 secs.  A simple way of determining the "best" might be to return the sample from the set which has the highest accuracy rating.  If there are multiple samples with the same accuracy rating, return the latest.  Another thing you can do is average all the samples from a given set together, or just all the samples with the same accuracy.  This won't improve overall accuracy due to the geometric nature of GPS error, but will reduce variance; you'd be reducing your maximum error by increasing your minimum error.  You'd also be introducing a bit of a lag effect in the cases where the device is moving, which may or may not be an issue depending on your application.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically not possible to get an accuracy of 2-3m using GPS when indoors.

GPS requires a reasonably clear line of site to the satellites, so the further indoors you are the less accurate it gets.

To determine your location indoors Android will try use the GPS, then triangulation using known locations of surrounding WIFI access points, then cell tower triangulation. It probably combines these 3 to provide a more accurate guess.

To determine location indoors really accurately you would need to have a fairly large number of WIFI access points in locations that are known to Google. I'm pretty sure thats how they do their indoor shopping mall navigation stuff.

Other tricks you could use to improve your accuracy (or to throw out inaccurate readings) could be to read data from the accelerometers (or gyros etc), and use those readings to try and determine when the device isn't moving, or the rate it is moving in a certain direction. Anything using these techniques is likely to be pretty tricky to implement.

Comment: How much accuracy can i get outdoors?

Comment: Accuracy outdoors really depends on the type of landscape you are in. In flat countryside you can achieve an accuracy of about 1m, in the middle of a city with large skyscrapers that accuracy can drop to 50m or so.